# access class of a material design item from a component's style

Tags: angular, material-design

I have a component that uses the `md-list-item` directive.

That directive will generate a div with class named `md-list-item`.

The problem is that I am unable to add styles to the `md-list-item` class from within the styles attribute of my component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <a md-list-item>
    </a>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .md-list-item{
      // I would like to be able to add css rules
      // for the md-list-item class here
    }
  `]
})
```

Is there a way to edit the `md-list-item` class from within the component style attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been wondering the same thing! I have had to resort to doing a few inline styles on the material components. I wish the documentation had the information regarding it.

A quick fix but not ideal...
`<p md-line style="margin: 5px;"`

Answer (score -1):

so a couple things based on the code you've provided:

You're actually passing `md-list-item` as an *attribute* directive, not a directive *selector*. The actual element itself is an `a` tag; Angular uses the attribute `md-list-item` to attach functionality to it, but you wouldn't be able to select it with a CSS *class* selector as you have done.

**Per the specs, it may be easier to do this:**

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item>
    <a href="your-link-here">Other List Content Here</a>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

and target it like so:

```
/*notice we're selecting an element and not a class*/
md-list-item { 
  style: stuff;
}

md-list-item a {
  text: stuff
}
```

This should work better with the MD directives and allow them to wrap content as they should.

If for whatever reason this doesn't work for you, you can add a class to the `<a md-list-item>` and target it that way, or you can use the CSS attribute selector:

```
a[md-list-item] {
  ....
}
```

...although generally that's a lot slower.

**EDIT** [Here's a Plunker of all three solutions.](http://plnkr.co/edit/pjhtKRt63hkuK8YPARsZ?p=preview)